# Make Excel Sheet With Multiple Ultra Win Grid (UltraGridExcelExport)

Tags: excel, export

Dear All Friends
     I Have One Window Form Which Have 5 Grid Of Infragistics Ultra Grid. I Want To Export All Grid TO Excel File. Now Problem Is That. In Need All 5 Grids In On Sheet As Shown As Form. So Please Help To Solve.

Currently I Export Only One Grid To Excel Using Infragistics Inbuild Method

```
   UltraGridExport.Export(UltraGrid,FileName)
```

Suggest Me With Multiple Grid Export In One Sheet.

Thank To All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  string StrFile = Application.StartupPath + "\\EmpLevDetView.xls";
                    Workbook WB = new Workbook();
                    WB.Worksheets.Add("Detail");
                    ExcelExport.Export(UltGrdDet, WB.Worksheets["Detail"], 0, 0);
                    WB.Worksheets.Add("Summary");
                    ExcelExport.Export(UltGrdSum, WB.Worksheets["Summary"], 0, 0);
                    BIFF8Writer.WriteWorkbookToFile(WB, StrFile);
                    System.Diagnostics.Procesenter code heres.Start(StrFile);
```

Answer (score 4):

How about exporting the results into multiple sheets on the workbook?

Create a workbook and then for each grid create a worksheet on the workbook and then export the grid to the worksheet.

```
public static void ExportToExcel<T>(this IEnumerable<T> grids, string filename)
    where T : UltraGrid
{
    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    UltraGridExcelExporter exporter = new UltraGridExcelExporter();

    foreach (T g in grids)
    {
        Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(g.Name);
        exporter.Export(g.GridControl, sheet);
    }

    workbook.Save(filename);
}
```